# C char array containing substrings to be put into array of strings

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, char

Given `char *line = {'a','\0','b','\0', 'c', '\0'}`

how would you make it so that `char **str_arr` would point/be assigned to all the substrings within `line`?

`str_arr[str_arr_index] = line` works only for the first substring, but anything after it is just NULL

Comment: You cannot initialize a pointer like that: you can use `char line[] = {'a', '\0', 'b', '\0', 'c', '\0'};`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
str_arr = malloc(3 * sizeof (char *));
str_arr[0] = &line[0];
str_arr[1] = &line[2];
str_arr[2] = &line[4];
```

There is no way to do it programmatically because there is no way to know how many substrings `line` contains. (Just as there is no way from the output of the code above to know that `str_arr` now has three pointers to three substrings.)

Answer (score 1):

First of all the statement

```
char *line = {'a','\0','b','\0', 'c', '\0'}
```

is not valid this can only be an array like the following

```
char *line = {'a','\0','b','\0', 'c', '\0'}
```

Here is a code sample that generates substrings

```
#include "stdlib.h"
#include "stdio.h"

int main()
{   
    char line[] = {'a','\0','b','\0', 'c', 'v', '\0', 'd', 'e', '\0'};
    
    int size = sizeof(line) / sizeof(char);
    int count = 0;
    int start = 0;
    
    char *str_arr[size];   // the size can be optimized with reallocs or by counting the terminatin chars in the line
    
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
        if (line[i] == '\0') {
            str_arr[count] = &line[start];
            printf("string #%d -> %s \n", count + 1, str_arr[count]);
            start = i + 1;
            ++count;
        }
    }   
    
    return 0;
}
```